# SignalR 404 when connecting using .Net Client

Tags: signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

What is the URL do we need to put, when connecting to SignalR core.
When we try to put **Url** as `https://localhost:44308`, it says not found. Yes web server is running. Any suffix is required?

```
        HubConnection connection;
        connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl(**Url**)
            .Build();
        await connection.StartAsync();
        bool isClosed = false;
        connection.Closed += async (error) =>
        {
            isClosed = true;
            await Task.Delay(new Random().Next(0, 5) * 1000);
            await connection.StartAsync();
        };
        if (isClosed == false)
        {
            connection.InvokeAsync("NewMessage", "from server", $"{DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()}").Wait();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Changes in Signal Core:
https://localhost:44308 should contain, Hub suffix, so correct URL is:

> https://localhost:44308/hub

this is configurable in Startup.cs